# React combineReducers create action for secondReducer after firstReducer finished

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have several reducers and using combineReducers

```
`export default combineReducers({
firstReducer: firstReducer,
secondReducer: secondReducer});`
```

I want to trigger secondReducer only when have firstReducer data in state.
What is the correct approach?

Comment: If we're talking Flux/Redux and therefore _actions_ you shouldn't be attempting to make conditional reducers at the export/import stage. What you want to do is check that state object A has a particular value (set by action A), then allow action B to be called from event B. It can then update state B via its reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:
http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html

Try it please.